# Calculate R-Square for PolynomialCurveFitter in Apache commons-math3

Tags: java, java-8, regression, apache-commons, apache-commons-math

Apache `commons-math3` (version `3.6.1`) classes like `OLSMultipleLinearRegression`, `SimpleRegression` provide a method that calculates `RSquare` (i.e `calculateRSquared()`, `getRSquare()` respectively). But I am not able to find any such method for `PolynomialCurveFitter` ?

Right now I am doing it myself like below. Is there any such method in common-math which does this?

```
private PolynomialFunction getPolynomialFitter(List<List<Double>> pointlist) {
    final PolynomialCurveFitter fitter = PolynomialCurveFitter.create(2);
    final WeightedObservedPoints obs = new WeightedObservedPoints();
    for (List<Double> point : pointlist) {
        obs.add(point.get(0), point.get(1));
    }

    double[] fit = fitter.fit(obs.toList());
    System.out.printf("\nCoefficient %f, %f, %f", fit[0], fit[1], fit[2]);
    final PolynomialFunction fitted = new PolynomialFunction(fit);
    return fitted;
}
private double getRSquare(PolynomialFunction fitter, List<List<Double>> pointList) {
    final double[] coefficients = fitter.getCoefficients();
    double[] predictedValues = new double[pointList.size()];
    double residualSumOfSquares = 0;
    final DescriptiveStatistics descriptiveStatistics = new DescriptiveStatistics();
    for (int i=0; i< pointList.size(); i++) {
        predictedValues[i] = predict(coefficients, pointList.get(i).get(0));
        double actualVal = pointList.get(i).get(1);
        double t = Math.pow((predictedValues[i] - actualVal), 2);
        residualSumOfSquares  += t;
        descriptiveStatistics.addValue(actualVal);
    }
    final double avgActualValues = descriptiveStatistics.getMean();
    double totalSumOfSquares = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<pointList.size(); i++) {
        totalSumOfSquares += Math.pow( (predictedValues[i] - avgActualValues),2);
    }
    return 1.0 - (residualSumOfSquares/totalSumOfSquares);
}
final PolynomialFunction polynomial = getPolynomialFitter(trainData);
System.out.printf("\nPolynimailCurveFitter R-Square %f", getRSquare(polynomial, trainData));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been answered in [apache-commons mailing list](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/commons-user/201803.mbox/%3CCAF6DVKNmrHn-9wm9H95sx7k0PXKENBhq3i6p_3f1M_CHBX93Cw%40mail.gmail.com%3E). Cross-posting the answer

> OLSMultipleLinearRegression, SimpleRegression provide a method that
>   returns calculateRSquared(),
>   getRSquare(). But I am not able to find any such method for
>   PolynomialCurveFitter ?
>
> Right now I am doing it myself like below :-
>
> Is there any such method in common-math which does this?

"PolynomialCurveFitter" is one of the syntactic sugar/wrapper
around the least-squares optimizers.
No state is maintained in the (immutable) instance.

> ```
> private PolynomialFunction getPolynomialFitter(List<List<Double>>pointlist) {
>
> final PolynomialCurveFitter fitter = PolynomialCurveFitter.create(2);
>
> final WeightedObservedPoints obs = new WeightedObservedPoints();
> for (List<Double> point : pointlist) {
>     obs.add(point.get(0), point.get(1));
> }
>
> double[] fit = fitter.fit(obs.toList());
> System.out.printf("\nCoefficient %f, %f, %f", fit[0], fit[1], fit[2]); 
>
> final PolynomialFunction fitted = new PolynomialFunction(fit);
> return fitted;
> }
> ```

This is indeed one the intended use-cases.

> ```
> private double getRSquare(PolynomialFunction fitter, List<List<Double>> pointList) {
>
> final double[] coefficients = fitter.getCoefficients();
> double[] predictedValues = new double[pointList.size()];
> double residualSumOfSquares = 0;
> final DescriptiveStatistics descriptiveStatistics = new DescriptiveStatistics();
>
> for (int i=0; i< pointList.size(); i++) {
>     predictedValues[i] = predict(coefficients, pointList.get(i).get(0));
>
>     double actualVal = pointList.get(i).get(1);
>     double t = Math.pow((predictedValues[i] - actualVal), 2);
>     residualSumOfSquares  += t;
>     descriptiveStatistics.addValue(actualVal);
> }
> final double avgActualValues = descriptiveStatistics.getMean();
> double totalSumOfSquares = 0;
> for (int i=0; i<pointList.size(); i++) {
>     totalSumOfSquares += Math.pow( (predictedValues[i] - avgActualValues),2);
>
> }
> return 1.0 - (residualSumOfSquares/totalSumOfSquares);
> }
> ```

The "predict" method is not shown here, but note that the argument
which you called "fitter" in the above, is actually a polynomial
function:

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math4/analysis/polynomials/PolynomialFunction.html

Hence:
   `predictedValues[i] = fitter.value(pointList.get(i).get(0));`

But otherwise, yes, the caller is responsible for choosing his
assessement of the quality of the model.

You could directly use the least-squares suite of classes; then
the "Evaluation" object would allow to retrieve various measures
of the fit:

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math4/fitting/leastsquares/LeastSquaresProblem.Evaluation.html

However, they might still not be what you are looking for...